# Can we merge this both tag [android-p] and [android-pie]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

I noticed that [android-p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-p) and [android-pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-pie) tags  both are  used for Android API level 28(Android Pie)

I propose merging the tags [android-p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-p) and [android-pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-pie). Both are used for Android API level 28, known as **Android Pie**.

Questions tagged [android-pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-pie) :  3 questions
Questions tagged [android-p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-p)   :  62 questions

Comment: [android-pie] is now merged into [android-p]

Comment: The usual android version tag follows the pattern [android-X.X-name] though.. So it probably should be [android-9.0-pie] ?

Comment: @Floern thanks for pointing out, I didn't realize that [android-9.0-pie] also already existed. Both have been merged into [android-9.0-pie] now.